# Pin Assignment in ispLEVER Classic

Tags: vhdl, programmable-logic, isp, lattice

I have an ispGAL22LV10C that I'm trying to program. I wrote and synthesized the VHDL in ispLEVER Classic, but I cannot seem to figure out how to create pin assignments. Documentation on this is kind of lacking, how might I go about this? I cannot seem to find this fabled "constraint editor" in my version (the latest). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it on my own after an hour of searching. [As per the website](http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Support/AnswerDatabase/1/8/4/1844):

> ## How can I assign device pin out for GAL devices?
>
> The **Design Planner** (or the **Constraint / Preference Editor**) is not
>   supported for GAL devices. The pin assignments can be made either in
>   the HDL source code itself or you can let the software choose them.
>
> For ABEL, specify a pin number when declaring the pin.
>
> Example syntax for ABEL source pin assignments can be found in File >
>   Open Examples. Then browse to Examples > SPLD > gal > mlcount >
>   mlcount
>
> For VHDL or Verilog, use the attribute 'LOC'
>
> Below is an example in VHDL:
>   Syntax
>
> ```
> attribute LOC : string;
> attribute LOC of SigName: signal is "P[Pin#]";
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> attribute LOC : string;
> attribute LOC of out0: signal is "PA3";
> attribute LOC of out1: signal is "PF8 PA2 PB3";
> ```

Comment: This seems to work with "simple" signals. The problem I have is when I want to assign vector members: `attribute LOC of A(15):signal is "P15";`. In such case I get `@E: CD128 :"C:\users\public\documents\isplever\design.vhd":28:18:28:18|Expecting : before class of object(s)`. Any help with that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a different solution (with at least ABEL_Schematic):

In the 'Chip Report' there is a line with 'ABEL PLA file'. Find that file in your design directory and inside you will find the following line

```
#$ PINS .....
```

now here you can **reassign** the pins like "A11:13 A12:15 "..etc {signal name}:{pin#}

After done, just run the 'Fit design' (+create fuse map) again and voila, you have the right signals at the right place.